# react setstate not rerenering

Tags: reactjs, rendering, setstate

I have the following:

```
  onTransfer = async () => {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    try {
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      await this.props.myData.methods.transferBalanceToOwner().send({
        from: accounts[0]
      });

      let contractBalance;
      await web3.eth.getBalance(this.props.address).then(function(result) {
        contractBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(result);
      });
      console.log('contract balance: ', contractBalance);

      this.setState({ contractBalance });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Transfer to owner error: ',error)
    }
    this.setState({loading: false});  
  }
```

and I have the following in my render()

```
if (this.state.isOwner) {
  ownerUI = (
    <Container>
      <Divider/>
      <p>Contract balance: {this.state.contractBalance}</p>
      <Button loading={this.state.loading} onClick={this.onTransfer} primary>Transfer Balance</Button>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

For some reason, the contract balance is not getting update after OnTransfer.  Can someone spot what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not right way to use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

1. With `async/await` there is no **then**able
2. Put `await` statement inside `try/catch` block for  `success/error` check.

The correct way to do this.

```
let contractBalance;

try {
   //success check

  contractBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.props.address)
  this.setState({contractBalance});

}
catch (rejectedValue) {
  //error check

  console.log(rejectedValue)
}
```

Comment: log the contractBalance  and see

Comment: i tried try {
   //success check

  contractBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.props.address)
  this.setState({contractBalance});

}
catch (rejectedValue) {
  //error check

  console.log(rejectedValue)
} but I did not get rejectedValue. logging contractBalance is correct.

Comment: Is it really rejected?

Comment: that's what i mean, it was not rejected. setState was successful.

Comment: could you please log `contractBalance` only as I said above.What value you want to considered for rejection